# Increasing max-width css for full calendar ignores scrollTime

Tags: jquery, css, width, fullcalendar

I am using the [amazing fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and have it all set up.  i have the start time shown set to 7 am as opposed to the default 6 am.

```
{ firstDay : 1 , //Monday
  scrollTime :  "07:00:00"
}
```

this works fine with the standard max-width set by the example code

```
    #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]
however if I change the max-width in order to give myself a bit more room on a wide monitor, the first time shown drops back to 4am.

```
    #calendar {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]
Is this a bug or am I missing some setting?

Comment: are you setting an specific aspectRatio?

Comment: @MarioLevrero excellent, solved the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per @MarioLevrero comment

```
aspectRatio : 2
```

solved the problem, with 7am now being the top time again.